# Convert html input date to be workable with a javascript date object

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a html form where users can enter a date:

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
     Date:
     <input type="date" class="form-control" name="anydate" id="anydate">
   </div>

   <button name="SubmitForm" type="submit" onclick="GetDate(anydate.value) >Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function GetDate(dateform){
const inputdate  = new Date(document.querySelector(dateform)}
</script>
```

Which I want to compare to the current date,  in Javascript:

```
var dateObject = new Date();
let datenow = dateObject.getDate();

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
             "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var currentmonth = months[datenow.getMonth()]
var entereddate = months[inputdate.getMonth()]
```

How can I convert these to the same format? I want to be able find the difference in days between the two  dates, as well as write the month of the entered date.

Edit: I've added a function to my script to get the date when the form is submitted (not sure if this is the right approach?)
However I am getting a "cannot read property 'getMonth' of undefined" error when I try to run.

Comment: You will need to start by converting the html date input value in to a JS date. `const inputtedDate = new Date(document.querySelector('#anydate').value)`

Comment: Just tried this, not sure if the code was supposed to go into a script within html or my js file. But it is now resulting in an error?

Comment: It will result in an error if you tried to do it on page load, i.e. before #anydate has a date string value. If you do this as a result of your button click, and only if the date input has been properly filled, then you shouldn't get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function `GetDate` is not returning anything and is missing `.value`:

```js
function GetDate(dateform){
  return new Date(document.querySelector(dateform).value)
}
```

Then to get the difference between 2 dates you just subtract them:

```js
const DAY_IN_MS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
const diffInDays = (new Date() - GetDate('#anydate')) / DAY_IN_MS
```

In general, I advice to use a lib like `date-fns` if you need to manipulate and work with dates as it makes your life way easier